# SAS: Iterate over dataset names

Tags: bash, merge, sas, iteration

I have a sas program that merges two datasets containing information on a given city.  The city name is part of the title of every dataset, e.g. for Atlanta:

```
data work.AtlantaComplete;
merge dir.Atlanta1 dir.Atlanta2;
by mergevar;
run;
```

I would like to run the merge on a long list of cities without having to make a separate .sas file for each one. With limited knowledge of SAS I tried the following:

```
%let city1 = Boston;
...
%let cityN = Miami;

%DO for i = 1 to N;

data work.city&i;
set dir.city&i.1 dir.city&i.2;
by mergevar;
run;
```

This produced several errors, the main one being that %DO statements must be inside a data step.  This won't work for my task because the loop has to be defined before the first data step.

A solution that can be implemented within the sas program would be optimal, but I am also open to something like a Unix Bash shell script that provides each city one at a time as a system input to the sas program (similar to sys.argv in Python).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Many thanks to kl78 and Chris J. Mostly used kl78's answer but Chris J showed the need for double periods to resolve the macro variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several small mistakes in your program.
Executing a %do loop is normally done inside a macro. Also you dont use keyword "for" and need a % in front of the to.
 so try this:

```
%let city1 = Boston;
...
%let cityN = Miami;
%let N = 42; *or whatever your N is...;

%macro mergecities(citynumber);

%DO i = 1 %to &citynumber;
    data work.&&city&i;
       set dir.&&city&i dir.&&city&i;
       by mergevar;
    run;
%end;

%mend;

%mergecities(&N);
```

Instead of using the macrovariable citynumber you can directly use &N inside the do loop, but used with a parameter the macro is more flexible...

Comment: I tried this code but I got an error that dir.city1.data does not exist.  And the (empty) output datasets were called city1Complete and city2Complete rather than BostonComplete and MiamiComplete

Comment: My fault, you need to resolve to the macrovariable first, so you need to add two && first. So the && resolve to & and the &i to a number, and after this, it resolves to the variable value, fixed that in my code. e.G.for i=1: &&city&i->&city1->Boston.  Also last city must have a name like city42, not cityN.

Comment: Added the double ampersands and still getting the following: Warning: apparent symbolic reference city1 not resolved. Error: file work.city1.data does not exist.

Comment: I resolved the error. It needs double periods after the variable in addition to the double ampersands before it. Thanks to Chris J's answer for showing this

Answer (score 0):

If you have numbered macro variables, you use `&&varname&i` to resolve them. Also, by having your cities in a dataset, you can create the macro variables off the back of it, rather than hard-coding them all (plus the count).

```
data cities ;
  input City $20. ;
  /* Create numbered macro variables based on _n_ */
  call symputx(cats('CITY',_n_),City) ;
  call symputx('N',_n_) ;
datalines ;
Atlanta
Boston
Chicago
Houston
Texas
;
run ;

%MACRO LOOP ;
  %DO I = 1 %TO &N ;
    data &&CITY&I..Complete ;
      merge dir.&&CITY&I..1 
            dir.&&CITY&I..2 ;
      by mergevar ;
    run ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;
%LOOP ;
```

Comment: Good suggestion. If you have the cities in a data set (which I agree is preferable) I also might lean towards using `call execute` and avoiding macro variables altogether.